# How to display the node title in different region 2 using theme method in drupal 7

Tags: theming

I want to display the breadcrumb and page title in my main content area.

For breadcrumb I used `theme('breadcrumb', array('breadcrumb' => $breadcrumb));`

What should I use for page title? 
I have tried `theme('pagetitle',  array('title' => $title_text))`, but it is not working.

Also that how can I use the built in theme styles of paragraph tags or heading tags... 
e.g. I used the following for generating a table in built in theme style

```
theme('table', array('header' => $headers, 'rows' => $rows));
```

Comment: You don't need to use theme functions in your templates

Comment: Thanx for your reply...
You are right that we don't use the theme functions in our templates. Actually, I am making a module which doesn't have a template. In the module, I just want to display some data using my module which also modify the title of the page. And my theme display the title (sophistically) in a region named "pagetitle", I want to display the title in a different place on the page :) 
it's just a wish :)

Answer (score 4):

You're looking for the `$title` variable.

```
<?php print $title; ?>
```

[Here is a list](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!page.tpl.php/7) of all of the variables that are available to you in a theme file (for a page).

Comment: Thanx for your reply... "$title" actually returns the title text of the page... by the way, my theme is still not returning the title text when I use $title variable...:( 
Actually, there is a region defined in the theme "pagetitle" which displays the page title using some html and styles; I'm trying to get that region alongwith its title text and html styles using the method "theme(...)". I can get the breadcrumb alongwith html & styles with the method "theme(...)"... 
I hope you understand the question now.

Comment: You can't magically call a theme function and hope it will do what you need it to do :) theme('pagetitle') is going to call theme_pagetitle() which I assume does exist. Take a look at hook_theme https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_theme/7

Comment: Another example is that if I want to add a pager, i can use this code:
theme('pager');

Comment: right, pager and breadcrumb are already defined in Drupal, pagetitle is not